# Binomial theroem problem

Tags: binomial-theorem

I have a problem and i think that will be solved by binomial theorem 
I am not sure:

$20^n+16^n-3^n-1$ get $n$ to make that expression divisible by $323$.

Comment: Did you try anything at all?  Hint:  look for very small $n$.

Comment: The answer will be 2 but i do not know how . i do not understand you of getting very small n

Comment: I just meant that trial and error gives the solution almost immediately.  To be somewhat more systematic, note that $323=17\times 19$ and it is computationally a lot easier to deal with the two primes separately.

Comment: I tried to expand 20 to 19+1 and 16 to 17-1 to deal but i did not get anything

Comment: I'll write up an argument and post it below.

Answer (score 3):

As $323=17\times 19$ we just need divisibility by both $17$ and $19$.

Working $\pmod {17}$:  our expression becomes $$3^n+(-1)^n-3^n-1=(-1)^n-1$$

Thus, to get divisibility by $17$ we need $n$ to be even.

Working $\pmod {19}$:  our expression becomes $$1^n+(-3)^n-3^n-1=(-3)^n-3^n$$

Thus, to get divisibility by $19$ we need $n$ to be even.

We conclude that any even $n$ will work.

Comment: I tried it with calculator and did not get the solution

Comment: What do you mean?  Which $n$ didn't work?

Comment: Ok it works thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

So we look for a number that is a multiple of $\;17\cdot19\;$, so:

$$20^n+16^n-3^n-1=\begin{cases}3^n+(-1)^n-3^n-1\pmod{17}=0\pmod{17}\implies\;n\;\text{even}\\{}\\1^n+(-3)^n-3^n-1\pmod{19}=0\pmod{19}\implies\;n\;\text{even}\end{cases}$$

Thus, for example, with $\;n=2\;$ :

$$20^2+16^2-3^2-1=646=2\cdot343$$